# Visa might be late - What do I do?

Tags: visas

I applied for a UK Visa on the 4th of May (because someone I know and trust very much insisted that I take the help of a travel agent), and was told that it would be within 15 **working days** (which is 15 days excluding the weekends) that I would recieve my passport with the Visa stamped. Coincidentally enough, the date of my departure is the 24th of May (7:00 a.m. IST), which is exactly 15 working days after the date of application. My worry is, if I were to get my Visa on the 24th, would I still be able to board my plane?

Comment: 15 working days from 4th May takes you to 25th May, because of the U.K. public holiday on 7th May.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't check for any holidays. I'll be sure to next time. Thanks, man.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UK visas in India usually take hardly a week to process. 15 days is usually mentioned so that consulates are not blamed for delays. The UK High commission would be aware of your departure date and normally ensure you get your visa before that. You might like to track the courier to ensure they deliver your passport in time, after they receive it.

Comment: Good to know. Wish I'd known that sooner, but now isn't a bad time either, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

> My worry is, if I were to get my Visa on the 24th, would I still be able to board my plane?

**Yes theoretically**, as long as you have your passport with a valid visa at the time of check-in it does not matter when you received that visa. All that matters is that your visa should be valid on the date you fly in and on the date you fly out of the UK.

> the date of my departure is the 24th of May (7:00 a.m. IST)

**No in this specific case.** For a 7 AM departure, you will have to reach there at least by 6 AM, and by 6 AM you won't be able to receive your passport either via mail or via the visa centre. You can only wait until the end of working hours on 23rd, don't count 24th.

---

> Visa might be late

Visa might also be *refused*, have you planned for that?

You will probably receive a decision in less than 15 days, it can also be a refusal unfortunately. Whether you are willing to take such a risk is highly subjective. Some people will, some won't.

There are 3 possible outcomes of this siatuation

1. You will get your visa in time. **Enjoy your trip**.
2. You will get a refusal in time. **Plan for this**.
3. You will not get any decision in time. **Next time, plan ahead**.

UKVI strongly advises against buying a ticket before you get your visa.

Comment: Well, at least now, I know the possibilities, so thanks a ton for telling me that. I guess I never considered the worst, but I guess now I know it's important to do that.